# How can I print a multi-page bibliography in Latex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a problem with Latex bibliography.
How can I write bibliography on multiple pages? I have a .bib file with all my bibliography entries, but only few of them gets printed.

In main file I have this

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliography{./Bibliografia}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please extend your code to be a small compilable example, stating with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` demonstrating your problem.  While `\nocite{*}` should do what you want, there must be something you haven't shown that is preventing it.

Comment: Are there any errors when you run bibtex or latex?